# Obtaining $g$ an envelope function and $\int_a^b g(x)dx = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that we have a function $h(x)$, which is defined on an interval $[a,b]$ and we want to obtain a function $g(x)$ from $h$ such that:

1) $\int_a^b g(x)\; dx = 1$

2) for a given function $f(x)$, $g(x) \geq f(x), \forall x \in [a,b]$

How can I obtain such $g$ function?

I know that if we take $g(x) = \frac{h(x)}{\int_a^b h(x)}$, then we have the condition 1. But I don't know how to fit this to condition 2.

**Note:** A function $kg$ is said to be an envelope function if for a real number $k$, the function $k.g(x) \geq f(x)$, for all $x$ in a given domain. So, in this case, if we could find such $k$, I want that the integral of this envelope function to be 1. In general, if we know $g$,
$$k = max\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "For a given function $f$, $g \geqslant f$." This will certainly be impossible unless you impose some other condition on $f$.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought too. Thanks.